# I need to get json using http when loading the app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

***I am not getting result when i am loading the app.***

but i am getting the result when clicking the button

```
<button ion-item  (click)="goToDrivePage()">
```

but i need to load automatically when loading the app.
any body help to get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your app component constructor or ngInit function like

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
            this.dataService.getData()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.data = data;
            });
        }
//OR
constructor() {
            this.dataService.getData()
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.data = data;
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: In my home component i have declared     item : any[] = []; and below i have created onload function 
ngOnInit() {
           this.wsp.getCategoryDetails()
           .subscribe(data => {
               this.item = data;
           });
       } and in web service i have created function    given below getCategoryDetails(){

  return [{'name':'ramu'}];
} but i am getting error like "TypeError  this.wsp.getCategoryDetails()
           .subscribe is not function HomePage.prototype". Kindly tell me the what is the issue?

Comment: That's exactly what I told you.

Comment: Umar can u help me to get resolve the above issue "TypeError this.wsp.getCategoryDetails() .subscribe is not function HomePage.prototype"

Comment: @RamuMothukuri Can you please add your code of component and service? Then I'll be able to tell you exact issue.

Comment: Hi Umar, It's working  like a charm. Thanks for great help

Comment: @RamuMothukuri Vote up if you can. Thanks in advance.